# Convert .txt file to HTML

Tags: html, vba

When I manually save the .txt file into HTML using Notepad++ a well formatted table is generated in explorer. I am trying to achieve the same by a VBA code. Is it possible to convert a .txt file into HTML using VBA?

The text in note pad looks like this -

```
WBC AU Equity</TD><TD>US96122UAA25</TD><TD>WSTP 5 PERP</TD><TD>1.09%</TD><TD>0.24</TD><TD>US96122UAA25</TD><TD>WSTP 5 PERP
```

Thank you.

Comment: If the text file contains well-formatted html, you just need to change the extension. You can do that in VBA with the [NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement) statement. What you posted is not well-formatted html and just saving it with Notepad++ is not going to change that. I don't know what it looks like in Explorer but it is definitely does not look like a table when I opened it in Chrome.

Comment: HTML files are text files. There is no conversion needed.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. NAME statement solved it.